# Exception handling with Apex (force.com)

Tags: apex-code

Is there any way to throws an standard or custom exception with Apex method as,

```
 private void createNewJob() throws RecordNotFoundException { 

  try {         
         // Some DML operation                
      } catch (Exception e) {  
         System.Debug('Error: Object not found');
         throw new RecordNotFoundException('Object not found');
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Define the exception class. Minimally, :

```
public class RecordNotFoundException extends Exception { }
```

Your throw statement looks fine.

Also, there's no need to declare that the method throws an exception type.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Ross! Thanks a lot for your feed back. Yes I have done that way. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Ross! Sure.. I have done that. Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I think following can help you. It has complete example of SFDC APEX standard and custom exceptions

http://share-salesforce.blogspot.in/2013/05/salesforce-apex-exception-handling-and_29.html

Comment: Please, try to extend your answer with more details from the link (which could become obsolete)

Answer (score 0):

We should not explicitly throw those standard or custom exceptions with Apex, code it self done that.

@Method that throws some custom exception (RecordNotFoundException)

```
private void createNewJob(){ 

  try {         
         // Some DML operation                
      } catch (Exception e) {  
         System.Debug('Error: Object not found');
         throw new RecordNotFoundException('Object not found');
      }
 }
```

@Can handle that exception as follow,

```
private void callingMethod() { 

  try {         
         createNewJob(); // Call above method                 
      } catch (RecordNotFoundException e) {  
         System.Debug('Error:Record not found exception ['+ e.getMessage()+']');       
      }
 }
```